# Wise for Windows

Tags: wise

I'm just playing with Wise For Windows Installer for the first time, and I'm trying to modify things so that the installation folder (INSTALLDIR) (currently c:\abc) gets sent to c:\program files\abc as a default instead... I'm basically trying to change the suggested installation folder that is offered when the user runs the installation script.

Anyone got any ideas how I might do this? I've played around with it for a hour, but I think the time has come to cast a wider net...

Cheers,

Martin.

Comment: Try casting a wider net and catch Inno Setup instead of Wise. Inno is easier to work with, perfectly reliable and free.

Comment: That might well be great advice, but I don't have control over our use of tooling... To borrow a saying, there's a tech lead for that...

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who has the same problem, it turns out that it can be amended on the Product Details page (the Default Directory setting...)

Martin